# Redux Saga not started?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga

I've written these actions and the saga to listen for them.

```js
export async function addToWishlistApi(id: number) {
  console.log("addToWishlistApi HELLO CAN ANYBODY HEAR ME");
  const res = await axios.get(WishlistUrls.add(id));
  console.log(res);
}
export function* addToWishlistSaga({ id }: { id: number }): Saga<void> {
  console.log("addToWishlistSaga HELLO CAN ANYBODY HEAR ME");
  try {
    const res = yield call(addToWishlistApi, id);
    console.log(res);
    const wishlist = yield call(getCurrentWishlist);
    console.log("WISHLIST", wishlist);
    if (wishlist.contains(id))
      yield put({ type: DealActionTypes.wishlistSuccess });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
  }
}

export async function getCurrentWishlist(): Promise<number[]> {
  const res = await axios.get(WishlistUrls.getWishlist);
  console.log(res.data.includes("WISHLIST-2.HTML"));

  const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
  const tags = $(".button.yith-wcqv-button");
  const idStrings: string[] = [];
  tags.each((i, tag) => {
    idStrings.push(tag.attribs["data-product_id"]);
  });
  const wishlist = idStrings.map(n => Number(n));
  return wishlist;
}

export default function* wishlistSaga(): Saga<void> {
  yield all([
    yield takeEvery(DealActionTypes.addToWishlistStart, addToWishlistSaga),
    yield takeEvery(
      DealActionTypes.removeFromWishlistStart,
      removeFromWishlistSaga
    )
  ]);
}
```

I'm trying to test with `recordSaga`

```js
import { runSaga } from "redux-saga";
export default async function recordSaga(saga, initialAction) {
  const dispatched = [];

  await runSaga(
    { dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action) },
    saga,
    initialAction
  ).done;

  return dispatched;
}
```

And here are my tests:

```js
describe("addToWishlistSaga", () => {
    const startAction: Type.AddToWishlistStartAction = {
      type: Types.addToWishlistStart,
      id: deal.id
    };
    const successAction: Type.WishlistSuccessAction = {
      type: Types.wishlistSuccess
    };
    const failureAction: Type.AddToWishlistFailureAction = {
      type: Types.addToWishlistFailure,
      id: deal.id
    };

    fit("dispatches a success action on success", async () => {
      const dispatched = await recordSaga(wishlistSaga, startAction);
      expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(successAction);
    });
    xit("dispatches a failure action on failure", async () => {
      mock.onGet(WishlistUrls.add(deal.id)).networkErrorOnce();

      const dispatched = await recordSaga(wishlistSaga, startAction);
      expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(failureAction);
    });
  });
});
```

The saga setup and test setup are identical to what I've used successfully in other projects, but for some reason `addToWishlistSaga` is never being run. None of the desperate log statements are being printed, and `dispatched` comes back empty.

What am I doing wrong here? My head is about to explode.

Comment: did you figure this out? I am having a similar issue with redux-saga. Have used it successfully in other projects but for some reason in a new project I have setup it is not picking up actions I've dispatched, they go straight to the reducer.

Comment: Well, I think what I figured out is that the successful runs I remembered were actually using the Saga Tester library instead of the `recordSaga` pattern. I'd recommend trying Saga Tester.